# Remote Desktop not working

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, remote-desktop, linux-mint

I'm trying to connect to an old Windows XP machine using the RDP protocol.

On the XP machine, I have checked "Allow users to connect remotely to this computer" and turned off the firewall.

When I try connecting from a Windows 7 computer, I get:

```
Your computer could not connect to another console session on the remote computer because you already have a console session in progress.
```

When I try connecting from a Linux Mint machine with the command `rdesktop 192.168.0.5`, I get a black screen and the console outputs:

```
Autoselected keyboard map en-gb
ERROR: send: Connection reset by peer
NOT IMPLEMENTED: PDU 10
ERROR: Connection closed
```

Why am I unable to connect to my old laptop?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before.. but I forgot the details why this is happening. However my solution was log-off current user from Windows XP before connecting with Windows 7. Not sure if it works with Linux client, you may give it a shot.

Comment: I have already tried logging off, still same problems.